# C++ Loop in menu

Tags: c++, loops

In my code there is a problem where even when I enter 'Q' or 'q' the program keeps looping the menu. What's wrong here? Here is the code:

```
{
    char selection;
    do {
        cout << "Add a county election file         A" << endl;
        cout << "Show election totals on screen     P" << endl;
        cout << "Search for county results          S" << endl;
        cout << "Exit the program                   Q" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
        cin >> selection;
    } while ((selection != 'Q' || selection != 'q'));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you type `q`, `selection != 'Q'` is true. If you type `Q`, the other one is true... so there's no way of leaving that loop.

Comment: are you talking of the first time?

Comment: Classic error `selection != 'Q' || selection != 'q'` should be `selection != 'Q' && selection != 'q'`

Comment: but I added a || so it should follow that selection = 'q' which is false therefore the entire statement is false..and I tried it with only one variable in the while and it still doesn't work

Comment: No `||` means if false if **both** are false, `&&` means false if **either** are false. Your understanding of Boolean logic is wrong, but this is a very common newbie error.

Comment: Put it another way you want to display the menu when the response is not 'q' **and** when the response is not 'Q'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use the And (`&&`) operator in your test, not the Or (`||`) operator. Otherwise, one of `selection != 'Q'` and `selection != 'q'` will always be true, and your loop will never exit.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out, the `||` does not fulfill your requirement. You need to use the `&&` operator.

If you press `q`, then this is the situation.

```
(selection != 'Q' || selection != 'q')
|---------------|    |--------------|
    true                  false
```

If you press `Q`, then this is the situation.

```
(selection != 'Q' || selection != 'q')
|---------------|    |--------------|
    false                  true
```

The loop should be like this.

```
while((selection != 'Q' && selection != 'q'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
} while((selection != 'Q' && selection != 'q'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `toupper()`.

If you do this,  `while ( toupper(selection) != 'Q'  )` you wont need to check both upper and lower case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{



    char selection;
    do {
        cout << "The Menu" << endl;
        cout << "____________________________________" << endl;
        cout << "Add a county election file         A" << endl;
        cout << "Show election totals on screen     P" << endl;
        cout << "Search for county results          S" << endl;
        cout << "Exit the program                   Q" << endl;
        cout << "____________________________________" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
        cin >> selection;
    } while ( toupper(selection) != 'Q'  );



  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```